# php loop and array where element has to be removed after 3 times

Tags: php, arrays

I am having trouble creating a **PHP** code that does the following scenarios,

Each of the 4 kids in the group have to eat 3 fruits. Once a kid eats 3 fruits, he has to be removed for the group and so on until the group is empty.

Comment: What did you try so far? What does "a kid eats a fruit" look like in your code? It "the next kid that eats a fruit" randomly selected from the ones that are still there? Please read the FAQ - it gives guidance on asking "good questions". This one doesn't really lend itself to a good answer yet...

Comment: Can you give us more detailed explanation about your issue?

Comment: "Please do my homeworks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$kids = array('Bob', 'Joe', 'Sue', 'Sara');

foreach ($kids as $key => $kid)
{
  for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
  {
    eat_fruit($kid);
  }
  // drop kid from kids
  unset($kids[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Impressive extrapolation from a poorly phrased question!

Comment: Unset is a function. use `()`. also the second i in the for misses a `$` (will end in infinite iterations ;) )

Comment: added missing () & $ - good catch in my haste.

Comment: <?php

function eat_fruit($kid) {

 echo "kid=".$kid;
}

$kids = array('Bob', 'Joe', 'Sue', 'Sara');
$i = 0;
foreach ($kids as $key => $kid)
{
  for($i=1; i<3; $i++)
  {
    eat_fruit($kid);
  }
  // drop kid
  unset($kids[$key]);
}
 this is my current code however it doesn't work, it only prints kid=Bob

Comment: add the $ and = to i<3 so it is $i<=3

Comment: @JamesDean - it's a lot easier to read if you edit your code into your question.

Comment: @dognose Because `unset()` is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions. http://php.net/unset